# How to generate a reCAPTCHA site key for React Native app

Tags: react-native, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, recaptcha-enterprise

I'm trying to add reCAPTCHA to my react native app. I'm using GCP's React Enterprise, but their [docs](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key) specify website, iOS app, or android app for the key's platform type. Will the site key for an iOS or android app work in my React Native app? If not, how would I generate the site key that works with React Native?

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, React Native is well integrated when it comes to Google Recaptcha. I think your question is more related to the mobile apps than the integration of both services.

**Will the site key for an iOS or android app work in my React Native app?**

That depends on the type of key that you choose to use, reCAPTCHA Enterprise provides score-based (no challenge) and checkbox (checkbox challenge) site keys to verify user interactions on your web pages and mobile applications. Both key types return a score for each request, which is based on interactions with your site or application. This score lets you understand the level of risk that the interaction poses and helps you to take appropriate actions for your site or application.

If you use the Score-based site key (recommended), it will be supported by websites and mobile platforms, unlike the Checkbox site key, which only supports websites. [Link](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/choose-key-type)

**How would I generate the site key that works with React Native?**

In the official documentation, they have a tutorial about Create site keys for mobile applications, and they mention that you can create only score-based site keys for mobile applications.
[This is the link](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key#mobile-keys).